# Ionic 2 - Angular Fire - Get Logged In User ID runs twice in the constructor

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 application using Angular Fire 2, I am trying to get `Current User Id` in `constructor`. However, I noticed that the `constructor` fires twice and though it show capture logged in user's `Current ID` the second time, the first time it gives an error, like the `currentUser` object is not defined. Below is the `constructor` code I am using;

```js
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private auth: AuthProvider) {
    console.log('Hello AnonymousTask Provider');

    this.userId = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    console.log(this.userId)

    this.taskList = this.afDatabase.list(`/tasks/${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}/anTasks`);
}
```

Below is the console snapshot showing the error message.

[image]

I couldn't really understand why the `constructor` is being fired twice. I understand that on the first time it fired, the `Current User` object might not be ready.

I tried to use `await` but the method is synchronous. Any suggestions as to how I could fix this, or what worked for you?

Comment: Please use the angular tag for angular 2+ questions and the angularjs tag for angular 1.x questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped using the synchronous way of fetching the user because sometimes it calls the function before the user is loaded which returns null:

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
```

Instead I now use the asynchronous way and subscribe to it, for example:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => { 
  this.userId = user.uid;
  this.taskList = this.afDatabase.list(`/tasks/${user.uid}/anTasks`); 
});
```

That way it makes sure the user is loaded before calling for the userId.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code why the constructor is run twice. Looks like the first time your user is still not logged in. What I would do is to check if the entire chain of `this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid` is valid. You can use angularfire's function to test if the user is logged in, or use nested if statements, or use a function [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38952313/1383356):

```
if ( validChain( this, "afAuth", "auth", "currentUser", 'uid' ) ) {
 console.log(this.userId)

 this.taskList = 
 this.afDatabase.list(`/tasks/${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}/anTasks`);
} else {
  console.log("User seems to be offline!")
}
```

As a side note, my experience with Angularfire was not fun. Each time Ionic got updated, I had problems with making it work. If you are thinking long term, I recommend using Firebase's own APIs.

Comment: you are right, AF is no fun because of things keeps breaking. Thanks for the suggestions though, i ll try n later update findings here